# Error missging property when $ref is used as part of an url in groovy script

Tags: groovy, azure-active-directory

I have a httpBUilder url which needs to be format as below:

"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/60a10121-9e1d-xxxx-xxxxx/members/$ref"

This format url is used by MS Graph API to reference a user

When using in in Groovy I get an exception as below

"groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ref for class: Script689
    at Script689.run(Script689.groovy:18)"

I guess that $ is used for property injection in groovy.

How can I solved it to get my url correct ?

regards

Comment: Could you please have a try to change the `$ref` to `\$ref` ? Or change the double quotation to single quotes at the beginning and the end of the whole httpBuilder url.

Comment: thanks it work by escaping the caracters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `$ref` to `\$ref`, it will work.